# memory handler of python logging module

Tags: python, logging

Anybody help me to add [memory handlers, bufferinghandler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html) to make my program  optimal (to flush buffered memory).

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)#we can set deug_level at logger level also

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)

logger.debug('This is a test log message.')
```

Comment: Could you describe your problem? In what way is it not efficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your memory handler just like you create a stream handler, passing in the stream handler as the target:

```
streamhandler = logging.StreamHandler()
streamhandler.setFormatter(formatter)
memoryhandler = logging.handlers.MemoryHandler(1024*10, logging.DEBUG, streamhandler)
logger.addHandler(memoryhandler)
```

You do *not* add the stream handler with `logger.addHandler`.